# using shift() to compare row elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have the sample data and code below where I'm trying to loop through the dataDF column with the function and find the first case of increasing values then return the Quarter value corresponding the the 1st increasing value from the dataDF column.  I'm planning to use the function with apply, but I don't think I'm using shift() properly. If I just try to return dataDF.shift() I get an error.  I'm new to python so any tips on how to compare a row to the next row or what I'm doing wrong with shift() are greatly appreciated.

Sample Data:

```
 return dataDF.head(20).to_dict() 

{'Quarter': {246: '2008q3',
 247: '2008q4',
 248: '2009q1',
 249: '2009q2',
 250: '2009q3',
 251: '2009q4',
 252: '2010q1',
 253: '2010q2',
 254: '2010q3',
 255: '2010q4',
 256: '2011q1',
 257: '2011q2',
 258: '2011q3',
 259: '2011q4',
 260: '2012q1',
 261: '2012q2',
 262: '2012q3',
 263: '2012q4',
 264: '2013q1',
 265: '2013q2'},
 'dataDF': {246: 14843.0,
 247: 14549.9,
 248: 14383.9,
 249: 14340.4,
 250: 14384.1,
 251: 14566.5,
 252: 14681.1,
 253: 14888.6,
 254: 15057.700000000001,
 255: 15230.200000000001,
 256: 15238.4,
 257: 15460.9,
 258: 15587.1,
 259: 15785.299999999999,
 260: 15973.9,
 261: 16121.9,
 262: 16227.9,
 263: 16297.299999999999,
 264: 16475.400000000001,
 265: 16541.400000000001}}
```

Code:

```
 def find_end(x):
        qrts = []
        if (dataDF < dataDF.shift()):
        qrts.append(dataDF.iloc[0,:].shift(1))
 return qrts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df.Quarter[df.dataDF > df.dataDF.shift()].iloc[0]
```

Returns

'2009q3'

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, and really simple.  I was trying to use shift totally backwards.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [46]: x.loc[x.dataDF.diff().gt(0).idxmax(), 'Quarter']
Out[46]: '2009q3'
```

Explanation:

```
In [43]: x
Out[43]:
    Quarter   dataDF
246  2008q3  14843.0
247  2008q4  14549.9
248  2009q1  14383.9
249  2009q2  14340.4
250  2009q3  14384.1
251  2009q4  14566.5
252  2010q1  14681.1
253  2010q2  14888.6
254  2010q3  15057.7
255  2010q4  15230.2
256  2011q1  15238.4
257  2011q2  15460.9
258  2011q3  15587.1
259  2011q4  15785.3
260  2012q1  15973.9
261  2012q2  16121.9
262  2012q3  16227.9
263  2012q4  16297.3
264  2013q1  16475.4
265  2013q2  16541.4

In [44]: x.dataDF.diff()
Out[44]:
246      NaN
247   -293.1
248   -166.0
249    -43.5
250     43.7   # <-------------------
251    182.4
252    114.6
253    207.5
254    169.1
255    172.5
256      8.2
257    222.5
258    126.2
259    198.2
260    188.6
261    148.0
262    106.0
263     69.4
264    178.1
265     66.0
Name: dataDF, dtype: float64

In [45]: x.dataDF.diff().gt(0).idxmax()
Out[45]: 250
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` to find the `argmax` of `diff` greater than `0`.  Then using `get_value` to retrieve the `value` we need.

```
v = dataDF.dataDF.values
j = dataDF.columns.get_loc('Quarter')
dataDF.get_value((np.diff(v) > 0).argmax() + 1, j, takeable=True)

'2009q3'
```

***What about the speeeeed!***

[image]